# Array Shared Preferences Reconstruct TableLayout OnDestroy

Tags: android, arrays, android-tablelayout, ondestroy

I have an application which is supposed to work as a diary, where the user can imput some text and store it to future reads. Each entry is stored in a tableLayout one over the other.

I've got this texts in an array and i want the tableLayout to be permanently, i mean even if on destroy is called so i need to use Shared Preferences.

How could i restore all rows if the user opens my app after a reboot, for example?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you are using API level 11 or higher, you can use the [`getStringSet()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) and [`putStringSet()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) functions. Here is an example:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("YourApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

String yourArray = new String [] {"Hello", "World", "How", "Are", "You"};
editor.putStringSet(new HashSet(Arrays.asList(yourArray)), "test");
```

And get it back:

```
Set<String> data = prefs.getStringSet("test", null);
```

If you are using lower level APIs:

### Write it:

```
//context - a context to access sharedpreferences
//data[] - the array you want to write
//prefix - a prefix String, helping to get the String array back.

public static void writeList(Context context, String [] data, String prefix)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("YourApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    int size = data.length;

    // write the current list
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        editor.putString(prefix+"_"+i, data[i]);

    editor.putInt(prefix+"_size", size);
    editor.commit();
}
```

### Retrieve it:

```
public static String[] readList (Context context, String prefix)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("YourApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int size = prefs.getInt(prefix+"_size", 0);

    String [] data = new String[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        data[i] = prefs.getString(prefix+"_"+i, null);

    return data;
}
```

### Remove a whole list:

```
public static int removeList (Context context, String prefix)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("YourApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    int size = prefs.getInt(prefix+"_size", 0);

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        editor.remove(prefix+"_"+i);

    editor.commit();
    return size;
}
```

### Use it:

(This should be in your activity)

```
//write it:
String yourArray = new String [] {"Hello", "World", "How", "Are", "You"};
writeList(this, yourArray, "test");

//get it back:
String yourArray = readList(this, "test");

//delete it:
removeList(this, "test");
```

Comment: You are wellcome! If you are using API level 11 or higher, then please take a look at the beginnig part of my updated answer!

Comment: It gives so many errors... i mean, the first method: Write it. list is undifined

Comment: Similar problem in the next method: String [] data = String[size]; Sorry, i'm not used to working with list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16136/discussion-between-bali182-and-aldridge1991)